# Can't center a button succesfully within a container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I can't manage to center a button/link properly - no matter how I try to use `text-center` class (surround it with div or on the link)

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="{% url "users:postcode" %}">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

codepen here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdbPyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add: `justify-content-center` to the parent component. The code will look like this:

```
<!-- ******Key Features****** -->
<section class="key-features ">
  <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center"style="background: red">
      <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="{% url "users:postcode" %}">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

working pen: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/bMPOJM?editors=1000 ;

-- I added the background just to have a hint, that's something that really help me and allow me to have some perspective from time to time --

Hope helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `text-center` on your `btn` with `mx-auto` to force even left/right margins:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="key-features ">
  <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row">
      <a class="btn btn-primary mx-auto" href="{% url "users:postcode" %}">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```